# Cast Eigen::Tensor from float32 to Eigen::half (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, eigen

In a C++ Op in Tensorflow, I have an Tensor of type float that I would like to convert to type `Eigen::half`. How do I do this? I see Eigen has some concept of [`TensorConversionOp`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/classEigen_1_1TensorConversionOp.html) used for vectorized casting.

The Tensor comes from: `const Tensor& input = context->input(0)`
Right now I am getting the Eigen Tensor using: `const auto et = input.flat<float>()`

**UPDATE**:
This seems to work, but is it the right way to do this:

```
Tensor input16(DT_HALF, input.shape());
GetCpuCastFromFloat(DT_HALF)(context, input, &input16);
const Eigen::half* i_stack = input16.flat<Eigen::half>().data();
```

Comment: That seems right. Are you seeing issues?

Comment: why not `tensor16F  = tensor32F.cast<Eigen::half>()`?

Comment: Then I get: ```tensorflow/core/user_ops/bnns_conv.cc:340:29: error: no member named 'cast' in 'tensorflow::Tensor'
            input16 = input.cast<Eigen::half>();```